# how to set mutiple values to combobox as selected in extjs4

Tags: combobox, grid, extjs4

I am working in extjs4. I have view with following components-

```
  1.        xtype: 'boxselect',
            displayField: 'emailAddress',
            valueField: 'id',
            store : store

2.xtype : 'grid',

                selModel:Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel', {
                    headerWidth : 40,
                    showHeaderCheckbox : false,
                    ignoreRightMouseSelection : true,
                    checkOnly : true
                }),
                width :350,
                border : true,
                store : store,
                columns : [{
                    dataindex : 'firstName',
                    header : 'firstName'
                },{
                    dataindex : 'lastName',
                    header : 'lastName'
                },{
                    dataIndex : 'emailAddress',
                    header : 'email'
                }]
3.xtype : 'button',
  text : 'Add'
```

On this add button click, i want to add grid selected multiple values to boxselect's selected values along with its previous selected values and want to show those values in combobox as selected.
i tried it as=

```
var previousvalues = [12,13,14]
var newvalues = [15,16]

Ext.getCmp('comboId').setValue(previousvalues + newvalues );
```

But its forming combinely one emailId and setting it as one value, not individual emailId
 So how to perform this in extjs4

Comment: Your combobox and grid share the store? They both have `store: store`

Answer (score 0):

You can not contact two arrays with `+` operator in javascript.

ExtJs framework has build in function for merging two arrays [`Ext.Array.merge()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.Array-method-merge)

So you can set new values like this:

```
var values = Ext.Array.merge( previousvalues, newvalues );

Ext.getCmp('comboId').setValue( values );
```

Comment: Sir i tried as you have suggested. But its not setting values to my comboBox